# How to parse text file/need first char to use in switch statement

Tags: java, parsing, if-statement, switch-statement

I need to parse a text file using the delimiter ":"

Text file looks like this:

a : 29173 : He : James : 474937 : 2 : 4 : 1

t : 27184 : She : Susan: 474930 : 6 : 4 : 2

c : 28174 : He : Meg : 474931 : 5 : 4 : 1

p : 29190 : She : Robin : 474947 : 4 : 4 : 4

My first question is how can/can I parse the first character to use in a switch statement?
I was thinking something like the code below (which I put together... but am pretty sure is incorrect).

I know that I can read the first char & I know that I can use a switch statement with char(s) but I'm stuck on how to put the two together.

```
File file = new File("test.txt");

    // Read the file
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(":");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = line.trim();
            int index; 
            String type;
            String name; 

            String identifier = scanner.next();
            switch(line.charAt(0)) {

            case 'p': 
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                name = scanner.next();      
                break;

            case 'c':
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                type = scanner.next();
                name = scanner.next();
                int partyC = scanner.nextInt();
                int empathyC = scanner.nextInt();
                int carryingCapacityC = scanner.nextInt();
                break;

            case 't':
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                type = scanner.next();
                int creatureT = scanner.nextInt();
                int weightT = scanner.nextInt();
                int valueT = scanner.nextInt();
                break;

            case 'a':
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                type = scanner.next();
                int creatureA = scanner.nextInt();


            }
        } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

VS.

Alright so I've read-up and played around with this some and think I can just use an if-else loop. However, I'm getting a number of errors (below the code).

```
        File file = new File("test.txt");

    // Read the file
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(":");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            line = line.trim();

            int index;
            String type;
            String name; 
            char identifier = line.charAt(0);

            if (identifier == 'p') {
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                name = scanner.next();  

            } else if (identifier == 'c') {
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                type = scanner.next();
                name = scanner.next();
                int partyC = scanner.nextInt();
                int empathyC = scanner.nextInt();
                int carryingCapacityC = scanner.nextInt();

            } else if (identifier == 't') {
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                type = scanner.next();
                int creatureT = scanner.nextInt();
                int weightT = scanner.nextInt();
                int valueT = scanner.nextInt();

            } else if (identifier == 'a') {
                index = scanner.nextInt();
                type = scanner.next();
                int creatureA = scanner.nextInt();

            } else {
                System.out.println("This is not a valid line of input");
            } System.out.println("Identifier: " + identifier);
        } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at SorcerersCave.main(SorcerersCave.java:33)
```

Comment: Easier to help if you tell what's not working :) Compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just read the file line-by-line. Get the first char to switch as follows:

```
switch(line.charAt(0)) {

    case 'a':
        //...
    case 'p':
       //...
    //...
}
```

And instead of using a delimiter and doing `.next()`, use `String[] parts = line.split(":")` that gives you array of strings. And trim each element and for ints use `Integer.parseInt(parts[index].trim())`.

Also, you don't need `while (scanner.hasNext())`. Instead do

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    //split
    //switch
```

Comment: Thanks for the info & suggestions! I changed the cases as you suggested & that works! I also changed the while- that works as well. I'm still a little confused about the delimiter though... I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Delimiter applies for next() but nextLine() and split is better in your case.